# How to re-render a component after querying to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a Reactjs project with Login/Register forms.

After logging in, the user can update his data like first name, last name, email, address or phone.

The function update data works but I have to logout/login to view the changes in my component. If I refresh the page after update the props are still the same.

**My code**

**Front**

```
class Account extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      email: "",
      phone: "",
      deliveryAddress: "",
      errors: {}
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken;
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    this.setState({
      id: decoded.id,
      first_name: decoded.first_name,
      last_name: decoded.last_name,
      email: decoded.email,
      phone: decoded.phone,
      deliveryAddress: decoded.deliveryAddress
    });
  }

  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { first_name, last_name, email, phone, deliveryAddress } = this.state;
    const body = {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      phone,
      deliveryAddress
    };
    console.log(body);

    axios.put(API_URL + `/users/${this.state.id}`, body).then(res => {
      this.setState({ body });
      console.log(res);
    });
    toast.info("Vos informations ont bien été modifiées", {
      position: "bottom-center",
      autoClose: 5000,
      hideProgressBar: true,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true
    });
  }
```

**Back**

```
export const updateUser = (req, res) => {
  User.update(
    {
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      email: req.body.email,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      deliveryAddress: req.body.deliveryAddress
    },
    {
      where: {
        id: req.params.id
      }
    }
  ).then(user => {
    if (user == 1) {
      res.send({
        message: "User was updated successfully"
      });
    } else {
      res.send({
        message: `Cannot update User with id=${req.params.id}. Maybe User was not found or req.body is empty!`
      });
    }
  });
};
```

I think my problem is related to the token that I have to refresh. Because when I logout/login the token is changing.

Comment: try this.setState({ ...body }); and make sure that body has the updated data in response.

Comment: I tried but nothing has changed. And the console.log(res) correctly displays the updated data

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the `setState`

```
axios.put(API_URL + `/users/${this.state.id}`, body).then(res => {
  this.setState({ body });
  console.log(res);
});
```

This will set the state to

```
{
  body: {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    phone,
    deliveryAddress
  }
}
```

You should use `this.setState(body)` or `this.setState({ ...body })` in order to get this following state:

```
{
  first_name,
  last_name,
  email,
  phone,
  deliveryAddress
}
```

By the way your `toast` should be in the `.then()` after the `axios.put()`

Comment: Does the `axios.put` works and `console.log(res)` works ?

Comment: Yes, if I change the first_name field, it's correctly updated in the database and the `console.log(res)` displays the new first_name

Comment: I need to logout/login to see the changes, but I want to see them without logout/login